# Mocha tests sharing state because of bad scoping?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a file "mochatest.js" that looks like this:

```
(function(){
    var MyObject = function(){
        var myCount= 0;
        return{
            count: myCount
        };
    }();
    module.exports = MyObject 
})();
```

and a mocha test file that looks like this :

```
(function(){
 var assert = require("assert");

    describe("actual test", function(){

        it("should start with count of zero", function(){
            var obj = require("../mochatest.js");   
            assert.equal(obj.count, 0);
        }); 
        it("should be able to increment counter", function(){
            var obj = require("../mochatest.js");   
            obj.count=1;
            assert.equal(obj.count, 1);
        }); 
        it("should start with count of zero", function(){
            var obj = require("../mochatest.js");   
            assert.equal(obj.count, 0);
        }); 
    });
})();
```

My third test fails with:  **AssertionError: 1 == 0** so it feels like the obj in the second test is the same one as the obj in the third test. I expected it to be a new one.

Have I coded up something like a singleton? Why is count==1 in the third test? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I guess. I changed both and got the behaviour I expected.

```
(function(){
    var MyObj = function(){
        var myCount= 0;
        return{
            count: myCount
        };
    }  // <= note no more ();
    module.exports =MyObj; 
})();
```

and the way I setup the tests (just once in beforeEach)

```
(function(){
 var assert = require("assert");

    describe("actual test", function(){
        var obj;
        beforeEach(function(done){
            var MyObject = require("../mochatest.js");  
            obj = new MyObject();
            done();
        });
        it("should start with count of zero", function(){
            assert.equal(obj.count, 0);
        }); 
        it("should be able to increment counter", function(){
            obj.count=1;
            assert.equal(obj.count, 1);
        }); 
        it("should start with count of zero", function(){
            assert.equal(obj.count, 0);
        }); 
    });
})();
```